# How to select everything after the first white space using regex

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to get this via regex. I have a series of strings that all have the same general structure:

```
10-1:15 Build Support: (available)
```

A number, a space, a string following, a colon, and a string.

I need to extract the string portion after the first white space

```
Build Support: (available)
```

How can I regex this?

Side note: I'm on a Ruby project so I've been beating my head on https://rubular.com/.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/g6vuUZ/3. Don't know how to do it in ruby exactly tho.

Comment: @Eraklon this works! I didn't know I could literally just say [^ ] for the whitespace. Both yours and newimprovement's answers work. I'll use yours because it's how my mind kept trying to make it work. Thank you

Comment: If you are not wed to using a regex: `str = "10-1:15 Build Support: (available)"; i = str.index(' ') #=> 7; i.nil? ? nil : str[i+1..-1] #=> "Build Support: (available)"`. If `str = "abc "`, `i = str.index(' ') #=> 3; i.nil? ? nil : str[i+1..-1] #=> " "`. If `str = "abc"`, `i = str.index(' ') #=> nil ; i.nil? ? nil : str[i+1..-1] #=> nil`.

Comment: If you aren't picky about maintaining the previous spacing, this is easier:  "10-1:15 Build Support: (available)".split.drop(1).join(' ')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something quick I came up on rubular:

https://rubular.com/r/tlfeSPy7zhfRN7

I tried matching with a group of non word characters and then capturing subsequent word characters. Match 2 should be what you're looking for.

Comment: This works as well as Erakon's response above.